# Why can't I use php time() for a timestamp column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

I have a `timestamp` column in a db table. Saving values with:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `activated_at` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE `id` = 123;
```

works fine.

But when I use the php function `time()` to get the timestamp, it doesn't work. It only works using `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` for the column value. Question is why?

the column definition is:

```
`activated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

I'm using the php mysql extension (and yes, I know it's deprecated, but I have to maintain some legacy code)

Comment: `But when I use the php function time() to get the timestamp, it doesn't work.` -- how do you use it? Show us the code.

Comment: use date('Y-m-d H:i:s)` instead

Comment: @ArunKillu I know that I can use date - I already wrote this in my question.

Comment: @JanWy ok,it was just a matter of checking `echo time()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [time()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) in php return a unix timestamp and timestamp is a datetime type and it requeires a valid datetime value.If you didnt give a valid datetime value it will be storing like `0000-00-00 00:00:00`. If you want to keep your field as datetime type then you must give `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` in php

Also check the [documention of various date time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) types in mysql

Comment: Ah, I understand! I was confused because I thought mysql CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns a unix timestamp - but it doesn't, it's a datetime value as you wrote. When I do `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 0` the result is `20131029151327.000000`.

Answer (score 2):

`time()` returns a unix timestamp, but the MySQL timestamp column supports specific formats such as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS`.  You can easily do the conversion using `date` for PHP or `FROM_UNIXTIME` in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html)

> The TIMESTAMP data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. TIMESTAMP has a range of '1970-01-01 00:00:01' UTC to '2038-01-19 03:14:07' UTC.
>
> MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval. (This does not occur for other types such as DATETIME.) By default, the current time zone for each connection is the server's time. The time zone can be set on a per-connection basis. As long as the time zone setting remains constant, you get back the same value you store. If you store a TIMESTAMP value, and then change the time zone and retrieve the value, the retrieved value is different from the value you stored. This occurs because the same time zone was not used for conversion in both directions. The current time zone is available as the value of the time_zone system variable. For more information, see Section 10.6, “MySQL Server Time Zone Support”

*nix timestamp and MySQL TIMESTAMP is not the same... that's why you need convert from *nix timestamp to MySQL timestamp over `date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unix_timestamp)`

Answer (score -1):

if you want to use time() change the column type to varchar(15)